# Display only values from the data set into X axis ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

I'm having trouble on this.. I'm working on a line chart using d3.js. I'm having trouble to display the X axis tick text that uses date values ONLY in the data spreadsheet. When I develop the line chart, I saw it automatic generated the date values between the values from the Data spreadsheet. Here is a quick example of the data.

```
date,close 
16-Dec-12,53.98
16-Dec-12,67.00
16-Dec-12,89.70
16-Dec-12,99.00
16-Dec-12,130.28
23-Dec-12,166.70
23-Dec-12,234.98
23-Dec-12,345.44
23-Dec-12,443.34
23-Dec-12,543.70
23-Dec-12,580.13
30-Dec-12,605.23
30-Dec-12,622.77
30-Dec-12,626.20
30-Dec-12,628.44
30-Dec-12,636.23
30-Dec-12,633.68
```

So in this dataset, it has 3 different date values.

In the D3 line chart, I want to display those only the 3 different date values which are Weeks in the x axis tick text. However, the chart is generated other dates in between those data date values. Example below.

[image: You see it's displaying other dates in between]

I'm trying to display like this that only display the date values from the Dataset.

[image: I draw the line to cross out those dates]

I hope this makes sense. Is this possible? I tried to use .tick() but it only display '16-Dec-12' which it confuses me. I'm pretty new into line charts for d3.js =/

here is my snippet code. I hope this helps.

```
function getExtent(member) {
            var extents = [];
            dataset.forEach(function(arry){
                extents = extents.concat(d3.extent(arry,function(d){return d[member]}));
            }); 
            return d3.extent(extents);
        }

            var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain(getExtent('x')).range([0,width]);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(getExtent('y')).range([height,0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom');
xAxis.scale(xScale)
                    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %d'));

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient('left');

        var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d){return xScale(d.x)})
                        .y(function(d){return yScale(d.y)})
                        .interpolate('linear');
        var g = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('width',width)
                    .attr('height',height)
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        // Use this group for drawing the lines
        g.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'line-group');

        // Axes
        g.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'usps-multiline axis axis--x')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-40,20) rotate(315)");

        g.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'usps-multiline axis axis--y')
            .call(yAxis);
```

**Please let me know if you can view the sample pic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for a time scale. In D3, the axis is automatically generated, you don't have much control on the ticks.

The easiest alternative seems to be passing an array of the dates you have in your data to `tickValues`:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
    .tickValues(uniqueValues);
```

Here, `uniqueValues` is an array with the dates you have in your CSV, filtered to only unique dates (otherwise you'll have several ticks in the same position).

here is the demo with the CSV you shared:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var csv = `date,close 
16-Dec-12,53.98
16-Dec-12,67.00
16-Dec-12,89.70
16-Dec-12,99.00
16-Dec-12,130.28
23-Dec-12,166.70
23-Dec-12,234.98
23-Dec-12,345.44
23-Dec-12,443.34
23-Dec-12,543.70
23-Dec-12,580.13
30-Dec-12,605.23
30-Dec-12,622.77
30-Dec-12,626.20
30-Dec-12,628.44
30-Dec-12,636.23
30-Dec-12,633.68`;
var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.date = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y")(d.date);
  return d
});
var uniqueValues = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.date.getTime()
}))].map(function(d) {
  return new Date(d);
});
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([30, 570])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date
  }));
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickValues(uniqueValues);
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

PS: I'm using D3 v4 in the demo, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out and it works! I grabbed all the values as store it in an array. Then remove any duplicates and apply that array into the .tickValues(..) and it works. Thank you very much and the client likes it!

Answer (score 0):

If .ticks(3) doesn't work, you can pass a custom function into .ticks to ensure you get the ticks you want.

Here is a fairly [comprehensive axis tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes).